# Datagridview Check Box Error Default

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

I have a Datagridview in which a user will input data for shifts they have worked. I have a Checkbox to tick whether they require an on call payment for the shift. It's unchecked Value is "N" and when checked the value is "Y". This works well.

However when the user leaves the check box at it's default state from load, when i come to send it to the database i get an exception. How can I get the default value to always be "N" even if the user hasn't altered the box?

Error Message: Object Reference Not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: A lot depends on how the control is set up and what, if anything, is backing up the DGV.  Generally, CheckBoxes will have a value of `True` or `False` only.  You didnt mention what the exception is, so I will guess it is about DBNull - that means you didnt set a default value for the column.

Comment: Editing original Question to show the error message, I have set it with a default value.

Comment: That would not seem to be at all related to an issue with a default value.  Something you are referencing is Nothing.  Without the related code it is hard to say more, but as is, there is an answer which covers how to find and fix that: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/26761773#26761773)

Comment: Yeah this is why it's confusing me because If I leave it as unchecked from form load then I get the error. However, if I check it I get "Y" and then Uncheck it again I get "N". For some reasons when it remains unchecked from load it doesn't get the False Value.

Comment: Sorry, but is something in your *code* that causes this.  Without seeing that, everything is just a guess. If you are getting an NRE, that link should help.

Answer (score 0):

You need declare the checkbox in the datagrid item_databound

```
     Private Sub dataGrid_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dataGrid.ItemDataBound

            If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Or (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
               dim checkbox as checkbox = e.item.findControl("yourCheckboxID")
            end if
     end sub
```